# Doesn't work onCreateContextMenu in Android

Tags: java, android

Created two `TextView` and call method `registerForContextMenu` method, called @override method `onCreateContextMenu` but when I clicked into `textViews` it doesn't work following procedure.what might be reason for it ?

```
TextView color,size;

    final int COLOR_RED = 1;
    final int COLOR_BLUE = 2;

    final int SIZE_26 = 26;
    final int SIZE_30 = 30;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        color = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.color);
        size = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.size);
        Log.d("nimae","ishla");
        registerForContextMenu(color);
        registerForContextMenu(size);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {

            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.color:
                    menu.add(0,COLOR_RED,0,"Qizil");
                    menu.add(0,COLOR_BLUE,0,"Ko`k");
                    break;
                case R.id.size:
                    menu.add(0,SIZE_26,0,"26 size");
                    menu.add(0,SIZE_30,0,"30 size");
                    break;
            }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear your question since you did not submitted full code, i think it may work for you.

```
   textViews.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       registerForContextMenu(color);
       registerForContextMenu(size);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but registerForContextMenu doesn't react in my app

Comment: onCreate method calls only one time when your activity first lunch.  If you want to react your registerForContextMen you need to put this method inside Listener method when you click any event.

Comment: I did exactly what you said but still no result

Answer (score 0):

after clicking TextView I should use method openContextMenu(View v); following code is working in my case

```
  color = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.color);
    size = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.size);
    registerForContextMenu(color);
    registerForContextMenu(size);
    color.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            openContextMenu(color);
    });
    size.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        openContextMenu(size);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Should use "long click" to invoke **ContextMenu**